# Is this thing sort of mocking religion?

Tags: kuffar

One of my little cousins say *Heaven* when she wants to say that this person is good , and she says *Hell* when he is bad.

If one heard this and laughed at her, did he mock religion in this case ?

Comment: not a clear question.

Comment: my aunt asked my cousin if she thinks I am good , and she answered her "to heaven "  , I laughed at this , did I mock heaven and hell in this case or not , @thetruthseeker this is what question is all about

Comment: Hope it is clear enough now

Comment: it is still not clear to me, what does "to heaven" mean if you think of it as an answer to "Am I good?"

Comment: she is about 3 years old , when she said "to heaven " means that she loves me , that I am good

Comment: it's 70% not mocking religion , but the problem is my whispers drive me crazy sometimes

Comment: Got it. no this is not same as mocking one religion.

Comment: Hey.. Don't say this is off-topic can I have your contact I really love you brother , I mean you always answer me nicely , you are a muslim , you are great @thetruthseeker , plus we're both truth seekers , if you are a male , give me a cotnact , because we really need to talk

Answer (score 3):

Becoming a Kafir in the sense of laughing at religion:

> وَلَئِن سَأَلْتَهُمْ لَيَقُولُنَّ إِنَّمَا كُنَّا نَخُوضُ وَنَلْعَبُ ۚ
>   قُلْ أَبِاللَّـهِ وَآيَاتِهِ وَرَسُولِهِ كُنتُمْ تَسْتَهْزِئُونَ / لَا
>   تَعْتَذِرُوا قَدْ كَفَرْتُم بَعْدَ إِيمَانِكُمْ ۚ إِن نَّعْفُ عَن
>   طَائِفَةٍ مِّنكُمْ نُعَذِّبْ طَائِفَةً بِأَنَّهُمْ كَانُوا مُجْرِمِينَ
>
> And if you should question them, they would certainly say: We were
>   only idly discoursing and sporting. Say: Was it at Allah and His
>   communications and His Apostle that you mocked? / Do not make excuses;
>   you have denied indeed after you had believed; if We pardon a party of
>   you, We will chastise (another) party because they are guilty.
>   [9:65,66]

is totally different from what you are asking about. The ill and wrong Intentions are the key point to their Kufr, not their laughing. However, this doesn't allow such idly behavior as well, we should be respectful about such concepts and such idly behavior can gradually change our attitude and intention against the religion, and it will be then that someone will be Kafir.

In Islam we have both "**how to be in hide**" and "**how to appear in open**", the former is a source of appearing behavior in open and the latter can root inside us so to change our inside, that's why we have "شعائر" and شعار (motto) when is repeated regularly can change into شعور (consciousnesses) and decorate our inside. Now we should choose what we are to repeat as our شعار, and respecting the religion of our Lord is among those things that we should care much. Laughing at such issues Idly does not necassarily imply Kufr, but it can and probably will bring Kufr to our lives at least in some respects.

However, your case seems both to be "*fear of Allah not to do anything wrong even though small*" and "*Satanic inspiration*" (وسواس), if so then you need to balance them and for that simply learn the rules of Islam (so that you know certainly what is forbidden and what is allowed) and follow them without caring much about what is encouraged or discouraged. After that when you evolved in being submitted to Allah then care more about every little thing that you scare about it if it is problematic or not. Just a piece of advice, and Allah knows best.

Comment: Thank you so much , can you tell me more what to do in this case , I didn't mean that to mock the religion , it just the way she said it  , and cuz she is little girl

Comment: it's not like I said that what she did was right , I know that she is not supposed to say this

Comment: @Fuadkhattab, I'm not a scholar brother, and at the same time fear from being told "...  لِمَ تَقُولُونَ مَا لَا تَفْعَلُونَ" and " أَتَأْمُرُونَ النَّاسَ بِالْبِرِّ وَتَنسَوْنَ أَنفُسَكُمْ  ...". Only let me mention that one should always care about what he is saying. Note that the sins of tongue is much more than the sins of any other limb. Also tongue is known to be teacher of the limbs as it can directly influence other limbs. Also a rule of thumb is that if you care a lot about not loosing even a single millimeter then it may comes a time that you will loose some kilometers. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, it really depends on the situation for whether you cousins are blasphemous or whether they are using it as description for something which is justified. For instance, you can say 'if you fail to be a good Muslim, you will not go to heaven' that is fine - but saying 'that food was heavenly' is comparing Allah's realm with human creation, which is insulting to Muslims and needs to be punished.

So, really, yes and no!

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, no he is not mocking the religion.

It is good to teach our young the basics of Islam, and let them know that good people go to heaven and bad ones go to hell, and train them what are good things to do, and what are bad things to avoid.

However I see that laughing at this girl is a sort of encouraging her that she is doing something right, since if a child did something wrong his parents shout at him, laughing is the contrary (their unconscience says that this is a good thing).